# MySQL : Left Outer join with in clause integers

Tags: mysql, sql

Table-A:
Each record in this table maintains the list of attached documents for a given user
[image: Each record in this table maintains the attached documents]

Table-B:
Each record in this table represents single attached document for a given user. 
[image: Table 2]

I am trying to get list of all Table-B records for a given user along with Table-A records.
Where Table-A supportingDocIds varchar column maintains the list of Table-B's PrimaryKey idAttachedDocs(INT) using a comma separated which needs to be matched. So that I want/can read the corresponding Table-A columns for the matching records.

I tried below with no luck.

```
select a.*,w.month from attacheddocs a left join weeklyhrssummary w on a.idattacheddocs in (REPLACE(w.supportingDocIds, '\'', '')) where a.userId=w.userid and a.userId=138 ;
```

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

/Gopi
www.AlliBilli.com

Comment: Easy. See normalization.

Comment: Its not about users. None of the records are coming out as the issue with comma separated list of other table id's.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.userId = w.userid` in the WHERE clause makes this an implicit inner join. `a.idattacheddocs IN (REPLACE(w.supportingDocIds, '\'', ''))` is equivalent to `a.idattacheddocs = (REPLACE(w.supportingDocIds, '\'', '')` because the IN operator doesn't work like you're thinking it does..  It thinks `'1,2,3'` is a single item, not a set of items.

You probably want:

```
SELECT a.*,
    w.month
FROM attacheddocs a
LEFT JOIN weeklyhrssummary w
    ON  a.userId = w.userid
    AND FIND_IN_SET(a.idattacheddocs,REPLACE(w.supportingDocIds, '\'', '')) <> 0
WHERE a.userID = 138;
```

Although you may actually want an `INNER JOIN`.

Be warned that storing multiple items in a single field in a relational database violates [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  That is to say, it's considered a basic design flaw.  There are times when most levels of normalization can be ignored for good reasons, but first normal form is *virtually always* incorrect to ignore.  You should have a table with one record for each supportingDocID.   MySQL is unique in that it has a function like `FIND_IN_SET()`.  Most RDBMSs don't.